# Can there be more than one UK Standard Visitor Visa stamps in a single passport?

Tags: uk, passports, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I already have a (now expired) 6 months long standard Visitor visa stamp/vignette in my passport. If I apply again for a new standard visitor visa, will I get a new stamp/vignette in my passport like the last time (with the issue date and expiry date) or the same old stamp/vignette would be modified/altered/stamped to denote the new visa?

So my main question is, for standard UK visitor visa, will the person get a new stamp/vignette each time they are given the visa or the earliest one is somehow used each time?

I am asking this because I applied for a Standard Visitor Visa again this year and received my passport back. But I didn't get any rejection letter nor a new stamp/vignette in my passport. So I was really confused if this was the mistake by the Visa and Immigration office or I am not understanding how this works.

Comment: Why on Earth wouldn't they?

Comment: @JonathanReez I received my passport back for my second visa application and didn't receive any rejection letter nor any new stamp in my passport. So I wanted to know if this was their mistake or not.

Comment: @Zephyr OK, so your actual question is why you have neither a rejection nor a new visa. Please edit the question so it asks what you actually want to know.

Comment: What were the start and end dates on your first Visa? What are the dates of travel you were asking for a new Visa?

Comment: @simonatrcl my first visa was between Nov 2015 till May 2016.For new visa I was asking for June till Nov 2017.

Comment: You should also change the title to reflect the new issue, or possibly start a completely new question.

Answer (score 5):

The old visa will not be re-used. You will get a new one.